# Changing array dimension

Tags: python, arrays, dimensions

I have the following array which has the dimension (4,1):

```
[0,0]
[0,1]
[1,0]
[1,1]
```

How can I convert it to a (4,2) dimension to look as follows?

```
[[0 0]
 [0 1]
 [1 0]
 [1 1]]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your first "array" is not valid.

Answer (score 2):

There's a problem: your first "array" is not an `array`, it seems more like the output of 4 `list` objects.

Also the second "array" you wrote is not an array, look at this:

```
>>> [0 0]
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?
```

If you mean you want the array to be printed like `[0 0]`, then it's actually an array, since (thanks to @Wondercricket) `numpy` outputs the array like that.

Comment: `[0 0]` is the standard output format when using numpy arrays

Comment: Didn't know this, I'll edit the answer, thanks for the correction.